# A bijection from N^2 to N that is not Cantor's pairing function

Tags: functions, cardinals

Is there any other bijection from $\mathbb{N}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ other than the pairing function? My search so far has come up empty.

Comment: There are $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$ such bijections. Are you asking for **explicit** examples different from the Cantor pairing function $\pi$? One easy one is given by $\pi'(m,n)=\pi(n,m)$.

Comment: One common trick is to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. The map $(i,j) \mapsto 2^i 3^j$ is an injection $\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$; then map the $i$th element of this image to the $i$th element of $\mathbb{N}$ to get a bijection.

Comment: I don't know what this pairing function that we have to avoid is, but try composing it with any nontrivial permutation of $\Bbb{N}$ on the left, or $\Bbb{N}^2$ on the right, and you can guarantee a bijection different from the one you started with.

Comment: I assumed the OP just wants, informally, a different approach to this problem.

Comment: @user759562: Presumably the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here's an example. Let$$S=\{2^a3^b\mid a,b\in\mathbb N\}=\{6,12,18,\ldots\}.$$There is a bijection $\beta\colon\mathbb N\longrightarrow S$: just define $\beta(n)$ as the $n$<sup>th</sup> element of $S$. And there is a bijection $\varphi\colon\mathbb N^2\longrightarrow S$: $\varphi(a,b)=2^a3^b$. Now take $\varphi^{-1}\circ\beta$.

Comment: That is a **terrible** suggestion.

Comment: I've seen this before. I still hate it

Comment: @AsafKaragila I personally really like this one! It combines two basic ideas: recursive constructions (when we unfold $b$, that's what it is) and coding via prime factorization. Additionally it takes basically no effort to verify that it works (unlike Cantor's). It's also a good exercise to show that this is computable without using Church's thesis (whereas for the Cantor pairing function this follows immediately from the computability of basic algebraic operations).

Comment: @DonThousand See my previous comment.

Comment: @Noah: Well, then what is the number which is mapped to $(42,65)$? Can you find that answer is under a minute without using a piece of paper and/or a computer?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, but why should I? To me ease of calculation doesn't count for much.

Comment: I like this answer, but I admit Asaf's suggestion $\pi(n,m)=2^n(2m+1)-1$ (from the other question that this is a duplicate of) is much prettier.  (although I still probably could not compute $\pi(42, 65)$ in under a minute without any aids...)

Comment: @JairTaylor Actually, that's my favourite bijection between $\mathbb N^2$ and $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I got mixed up for a second there. I propose you rename the variables, so people don't get confused by the double use of $b$. Or, alternatively, rename the bijection. Moreover, you could also say $n$th _largest_, since you implicitly use an ordering on the set $S$.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K I've changed the name of my map from $b$ to $\beta$.